# DateTime in .NET 4.5 Issue

Tags: .net, date, datetime

I'm trying to parse a DateTime in .NET 4.5. This is the code.

```
var rawDatetime = "10-11-2012, 11:19 AM";
var format = "MM-dd-yyyy, hh:mm tt";
var ok = DateTime.TryParseExact(rawDateTime, format, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

This gives `ok==false`, and `dateTime=010101`. What am I doing wrong? Does the framework have a bug?

Fixed with "DateTime.TryParseExact(rawDateTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);"

Comment: Your code should work (also there is a type in `rawDateTime` variable name)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure this isn't the typo of `rawDatetime` vs `rawDateTime` (which are different variables and could have different values)?

It works fine for me:

```
var rawDateTime = "10-11-2012, 11:19 AM";
var format = "MM-dd-yyyy, hh:mm tt";
DateTime dateTime;
var ok = DateTime.TryParseExact(rawDateTime, format, new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
if (ok)
{   // following prints correctly
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have solved my problem even though I still don't know why it didn't work. I just removed en-US as CultureInfo DateTime.TryParseExact(rawDateTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);.